# Reverse proxy Traefik to Nginx in Docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, traefik

This is necessary as Traefik doesn't support php-fpm.

This docker-compose.yml doesn't work:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #php
  ...
  
  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network
      - traefik
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.webserver.rule=Host(`nginx.your_domain`)
      - traefik.http.routers.webserver.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.webserver.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
      - traefik.port=80

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
  traefik:
    external: true
```

However, if I make an innocuous edit like change the version number to `3.7` (or change back to `3`, from `3.7`) it suddenly works, but isn't consistent.

How do I successfully route Traefik to an Nginx container?

Answer (score 0):

#1. Docker compose file version is related to the engine, so please make sure you match that:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

#2. You could try to run the basic example from Traefik:

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/
I'm assuming this is traefik latest (2.4)